# Ademco Alarm — identify these things on the wall?

Tags: security, alarm

Purchased a home built in 1999 and it has several of these things on the wall that are part of an ADEMCO-made security system.

Can you identify what the purpose of these devices?   The yellow light appears to blink when any one of doors in the room opens or shuts.

[image: photo of wall mounted device]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a glass impact/break sensor. It is wall mounted and hard wired back to the control panel. It detects impact and actual glass breaking up to about 30 feet.

Per @Menace, clap your hands near them and they should light up.

Comment: Clap your hands near them and they should light up

Comment: @Menace  Whoa, air pressure sensing!  That explains why the yellow light would light when opening or closing the door but not consistently.